# How to Index in TableForm

Tags: output-formatting

Why are the k-values 0,10 not showing in the TableForm below?

```
TableForm[RecurrenceTable[{u[k + 1] == (9/10)*u[k] + s[k] + k,    
s[k + 1] == (9/10)*s[k] + (1/10)*u[k], u[0] == 50, s[0] == 20}, {u,
s}, {k, 0, 10}], TableHeadings -> {{}, {"k","u[k]", "s[k]"}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply refer to `k` outside the scope of `RecurrenceTable`, but there are plenty of ways to add in a value.

```
TableForm[MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2 - 1, #1}] &,
  RecurrenceTable[{u[k + 1] == (9/10)*u[k] + s[k] + k,
    s[k + 1] == (9/10)*s[k] + (1/10)*u[k], u[0] == 50, s[0] == 20}, {u,
    s}, {k, 0, 10}]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"k", "u[k]", "s[k]"}}]
```

or

```
{kmin, kmax} = {0, 10};
TableForm[MapThread[Prepend,
  {RecurrenceTable[{u[k + 1] == (9/10)*u[k] + s[k] + k,
     s[k + 1] == (9/10)*s[k] + (1/10)*u[k], u[0] == 50, s[0] == 20}, {u,
     s}, {k, kmin, kmax}], Range[kmin, kmax]}], TableHeadings -> {None,
   {"k", "u[k]", "s[k]"}}]
```

Comment: All: Each of your recommendations was very innovative and most helpful; many thanks to all ... prg

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any reputation so I can't comment on or upvote Chris's answer, consider this an addendum (with an additional solution at the end):

We know TableForm should have a column of data for each heading (in this case 3 columns).

Dimensions of original data (11 rows, 2 columns):

```
In[]:= Dimensions@
 RecurrenceTable[{u[k + 1] == (9/10)*u[k] + s[k] + k, 
   s[k + 1] == (9/10)*s[k] + (1/10)*u[k], u[0] == 50, s[0] == 20}, {u,
    s}, {k, 0, 10}]

Out[]= {11, 2}
```

Dimensions of Chris's Data (11 rows, 3 columns):

```
In[]:= Dimensions@
 MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2 - 1, #1}] &, 
  RecurrenceTable[{u[k + 1] == (9/10)*u[k] + s[k] + k, 
    s[k + 1] == (9/10)*s[k] + (1/10)*u[k], u[0] == 50, 
    s[0] == 20}, {u, s}, {k, 0, 10}]]

Out[]= {11, 3}
```

Here's another way to get 3 columns:

```
TableForm[
 count = 0; 
 Table[Prepend[row, count++], {row, #}] &@
  RecurrenceTable[{u[k + 1] == (9/10)*u[k] + s[k] + k, 
    s[k + 1] == (9/10)*s[k] + (1/10)*u[k], u[0] == 50, 
    s[0] == 20}, {u, s}, {k, 0, 10}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"k", "u[k]", "s[k]"}}]
```